# update or add new data file to exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I first use pyinstaller to wrap my python script and data file to generate A.exe in Window10, and I want to add anthor data file to A.exe, counld I directly update the A.exe instead of useing raw python script ? example: `pyinstall another.data.file A.exe` to get a new B.exe? Is that possible?

thanks~